# Solving $\int \frac{1}{x-1}dx$ in two ways.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have some confusion with this integral
$$\int \frac{1}{x-1}dx$$

I can see the solution is $ln(x-1)$

However if I multiply the top and bottom by $-1$ I get

$$\int \frac{-1}{1-x}dx$$

And then the solution is $ln(1-x)$

But these can't be equivalent because if we restrict the domain to $\mathbb{R}$ then one is undefined at $0$ yet the other isn't. These integrals are part of a differential equation I am solving and depending on which way I do it I can or can't solve the initial value problem  $y(0) = 0$.

I have a feeling I'm probably missing something quite obvious here, can you help me see it?

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot integrate this across $x=1$, while $\ln(x-1)$ and $\ln(1-x)$ have different domains. (I am not the same >

Comment: Yes sorry maybe $(-1,1)$ would be a more suitable domain for my question than $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that$$\int\frac{1}{x-1}dx=\ln|x-1|+C.$$

Comment: Ah yes, of course... Thanks!

Comment: @Henry: You are welcome!